# How to configure local apache to support multiple local dev sites using wildcard subdomains?

Tags: apache

I have many web projects under

```
[/var/www/personal]$ ls
project1  project2  app1  app2  hello  index.php
```

I want visit these projects by access:

```
project.dev.me 
project2.dev.me
app1.dev.me
app2.dev.me
hello.dev.me
```

and when I visit `dev.me` it goes to /var/www/personal/index.php

So far I've added this to my hosts:

```
dev.me  127.0.0.1
```

and enabled vhost_alias mod in apache config,
and here's my virtual host configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName dev.me
    ServerAlias *.dev.me
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/personal/%1
    <Directory /var/www/personal/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.me.error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.me.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work.
I have two questions:

1) Can I get it work without adding every sub domain into my hosts file?

2) I can get the subdomains work if I add every sub domain into my hosts file, but what should I do to make dev.me point to index.php ?

Answer (score 0):

without running a local DNS (like [Avahi](http://www.avahi.org) or [Bind9](http://www.bind9.net)), there is no other way than to define individual hostnames in `/etc/hosts`. referencing a directory with virtual host configurations is probably most script-able (in order to automate vhost addition/removal) ... for example:

/etc/hosts (there are no wildcards available)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost dev.me
127.0.0.1 project01.dev.me project02.dev.me
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/conf.vhosts.d/*.conf
```

/etc/httpd/conf.vhosts.d/10-project01.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project01.dev.me
   ServerAdmin root@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/project01
   <Directory /var/www/project01/>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/httpd/conf.vhosts.d/10-project02.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project02.dev.me
   ServerAdmin root@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/project02
   <Directory /var/www/project02/>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/httpd/conf.vhosts.d/99-localhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias *
   ServerAdmin root@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost
   <Directory /var/www/localhost/>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the config file check shows:

```
httpd -S
```

that ServerAlias * is only good for a final catch-all (eg. to show some project manager UI):

```
port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/httpd/conf.vhosts.d/99-localhost.conf:3)
        wild alias *
```